# Смена стиля, в котором находится элемент

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, ответьте на тупой вопрос. Есть код:

```
<li><button onclick="a(this)">Клик</button></li>
<li><button onclick="a(this)">Клик</button></li>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на кнопку изменялся фон *li*, в котором он находится?

Comment: Не вешайте в разметке обработчики событий, особенно используя jQuery.

А так вам понадобится .parent(); .css() или .toggleClass()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li><button onclick="$(this).parent().css('background', red);">Клик</button></li>
```

Однако вам правильно сказали, что обработчики лучше вешать через Js а не прямо в  разметке

Comment: @Артур Пантелеев, ох... иногда лучше просто промолчать.

Comment: @Deonis, ну конкретную проблему я ему помог решить...А вот когда у него будет 10, 50, 100 элементов списка, тогда он сам придет к тому, что обраотчики нужно вешать иначе.